# Permissions error when trying to install OpenEdx Devstack on MacOS

Tags: macos, devstack, openedx

So I am trying to install and run OpenEdx devstack on my mac through docker. I have been following the tutorial here https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/installation/install_devstack.html#installation-prerequisites-for-devstack

But when I run the "sudo make dev.provision" command i get the following error which I have no clue of.

"""

```
ERROR: for lms  Cannot start service lms: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/var/lib/docker/volumes/devstack_edxapp_node_modules/_data\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0fd6f478ae15da1b2c0930388535f89243bb0c392cf5d342e8305db878195a4b/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0fd6f478ae15da1b2c0930388535f89243bb0c392cf5d342e8305db878195a4b/merged/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/node_modules\\\" caused \\\"mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/0fd6f478ae15da1b2c0930388535f89243bb0c392cf5d342e8305db878195a4b/merged/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/node_modules: permission denied\\\"\"": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
make: *** [dev.provision.run] Error 1
```

"""

Can anybody tell what is going wrong here. I am using Docker v2.0.0.3 and have macOS Sierra running on my machine.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?